# Redirect to the url of the clicked (referred) link

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, authentication, http-referer

I have a scenario where the user receives an email from the system with a specific link which requires login. say for example the link is `http://test.url.com/product/2`. Where clicking on this link redirects the user to the sign in page and should redirect to the received url upon success login.

But the issue I am having is the system always redirects to the default location which is `http://test.url.com/dashboard`.

To implement this I used http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#redirecting-after-login `use_referer: true` in `security.yml` and to test it I have used `print_r($request->headers->get('referer'));` on the sign in page.

But this always returns `null` when I click the link from the email but, it returns the proper referrer url when I logout of the system and lands on the sign in page.

**EDIT - security.yml**

```
security:
    providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

    webservice:
        id: user_provider
    encoders:
        Project\Bundle\LoginBundle\Security\User\User: plaintext

    access_control: 
      - { path: ^/signin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: "^/(signup|forgotpassword|resetpassword/[0-9a-z]+)?$", roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }      

    firewalls:
      secured_area:
    pattern:   ^/
    anonymous: ~
    form_login:
      login_path: /signin
      check_path: _security_check
    access_denied_url: forgotpassword
      dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

      default:
    anonymous: true
```

Comment: how are you redirecting them to the login page to begin with?

Comment: @DerickF currently like this `return $this->redirect($link);` . my plan is to redirect to the referer link if it is not null

Comment: I just noticed that your posted urls have back slashes instead of forward slashes.  What was the reason for that?

Comment: @DerickF ohh my bad..i had typed it in by mistake :D i will correct them

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 choices:

You can either populate the referer manually or  you can have it populate in your controller by causing a login redirect by specifying it in your security.yml.  i recommend the security.yml way as i haven't actually tried the manual population because i don't trust myself or anyone else for that matter to always remember to populate the refer in those situations. security.yml also has the benefit of not having redirect code all over the place.

```
$request->getSession()->set('referer', $request->attributes->all());
```

or

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/product/.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer i will check on this and post back :)

Comment: I dunno if i am doing this wrong but this implementation did not work for me :(

Comment: @Hasitha can you post your security.yml?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I have updated the question with the security.yml

Comment: @Hasitha this is kinda silly but i realized i had a typo in each of my suggested solutions.  If neither work if you retry them, try changing security: false to be true and the access control should do the redirect work for you.

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestions but didnt work..thank you for the help. i think the problem is i call to a centralized authentication service which sits in another domain.