# Get current url within security.yml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

In my requirement, a user receives an email with a url, once he clicks the user will be navigated to the url via an authentication process.

So to redirect the user to the clicked url I am using the method mentioned here ( [Pass parameters when redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895263/pass-parameters-when-redirect) ) where I intend to pass the redirect url as parameter like

`login_path: %accounts_host%/signin?redirect=%need_current_url_here%`

within the `security.yml` and capture as such `$url=$_GET['redirect'];` and provide the redirection accordingly.

My query is how can I access the current url from within the `security.yml` so that I can attach it to the `login_path`.

I am quite new to this and any example/ document is very much appreciated. :)

**PS**

The authentication is done within another symonfy2 application at which point, I cant use `referer` command as it will be  null. That is why I am trying to pass thee redirect url as a parameter. :)

Comment: @CSchulz Its the same authentication process where I am trying to pass in the url to be redirected after signing as a paramerter within the security.yml.

Comment: It isn't the same like you are calling before redirected to the sigin url? Example: call yourapp/url => yourapp/signin => yourapp/url

Comment: @CSchulz I have tried this using the `referer` method but once it navigates to the signin the referer is always null.so thats why I am trying to pass in the url to be navigated as a parameter.

Comment: Is the url in the email the same as your target after the login? If yes you don't need anything. The security component redirects automatically back to the first called url after success.

Comment: @CSchulz the thing is I have a seperate centralized authentication process. so once the application reached that end the referer is no more. that is the reason I need the redirect url as parameter. and i should have mentioned this within the question. Ill update it

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @CSchulz ohh thank u for that i will check on this and post back (y)

Comment: If it helps you please vote, if it is the solution mark it as solution, thanks.

Comment: @CSchulz i did upvote but still am checking on it. I am kinda busy these days. I will mark it as an answer if it helps (y) thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use an entry point and a success handler.

security.yml:

```
firewalls:            # Required
    # Examples:
    somename:
        entry_point: some.service.id
        ...
        form_login:
            ...
            success_handler: some.service.id
```

SuccessHandler ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001496/390177)):

```
<?php
namespace StatSidekick\UserBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public function __construct( HttpUtils $httpUtils, array $options ) {
        parent::__construct( $httpUtils, $options );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token ) {
        // Create if necessary a redirect response otherwise use the parent one with
        // $response = parent::onAuthenticationSuccess( $request, $token );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Entry point ([source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/firewall.html#entry-points)):

> When the user is not authenticated at all (i.e. when the token storage
>   has no token yet), the firewall's entry point will be called to
>   "start" the authentication process. An entry point should implement
>   AuthenticationEntryPointInterface, which has only one method: start() ...