# dynamic parameters in security.yml

Tags: symfony, redirect, parameters, yaml

The isssue I am trying to address is to automatically redirect my application to the user entered url after login. Since I have a centralized authentication server I cant user 'HTTP_REFERER' as it always returns null when am being transferred to the authentication server.

My solution is to use the `security.yml` in my application server to pass the redirection url  as url parameter. I have implemented that as follows,

**parameters.php**

```
$container->setParameter('referer', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

**security.yml**

```
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        stateless: true
        form_login: 
            login_path: %accounts_host%/signin?referer=%referer%
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: app.security.authenticator
```

But my issue is that the `referer` parameter in `security.yml` is always static. It always gives the first application url I type in. Lets say if i type `www.appserver.com/product/1`, the next time if I type in `www.appserver.com/product/200` the `referer` will always return `www.appserver.com/product/1` in the authenitcation server.

However, If I do a `print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); exit();` in the `parameters.php` the value changes for my each request.

I was at this for quite some time and I am very lost at this point. Any help on getting this `referer` value dynamically on the `security.yml` would be really appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079592/how-does-symfony2-redirect-to-requested-page-after-login

Comment: @Baig thanks for the reference! will take a look at it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current url within security.yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898039/get-current-url-within-security-yml)

Comment: FYI, in production environments, your parameter will be cached. Which is why it's the first URL you go to. You'll probably want to create your own success handler instead. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler